# UISlider customize

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uislider

I am customizing my UISlider like this:

```
[[UISlider appearance] setMinimumValueImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_minimum.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)]];
[[UISlider appearance] setMaximumValueImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_maximum.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)]];
```

This somewhat works, here's the result:
[image]

It does something, puts the images on either side, but keeps the old style, and doesn't stretch my images. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: have you tried using `setMinimumTrackImage:forState:` instead?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
[slider setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"redSlider.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**Result:**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

```
[slider setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_maximum"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[slider setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_minimum"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in there. I think you missed `-stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:`